# Cannot disable ORMLites Logging

Tags: java, logging, ormlite

So, my problem is:

I need to disable ORMLites Logging.

I already tried

```
System.setProperty(LocalLog.LOCAL_LOG_LEVEL_PROPERTY, "ERROR");
```

On a JavaFX Application, this worked.
But now I have a console program where this doesnt want to work...
First theory I have is:

I am using an seperate Logger with a FileHandler. Does this maybe interfere with LocalLog? Setting the property works, but this does no change to the output.

Edit: Regarding differences between the both projects:

I use commons logging in the non-FX Project. Could this be the reason why it isnt working? (I use it because of commons csv and commons configuration... not for logging)

Comment: So -Dcom.j256.ormlite.logger.level=ERROR doesn't work from the command line?

Comment: When you say a separate `Logger`, what do you mean?  slf4j or something?

Comment: No, just the usual util.logging Logger. But i use a Logger via (Logger.getLogger(herehaveaclassname); I will test the parameter.

Comment: No success, -Dcom.j256.ormlite.logger.level=ERROR does not work for the command line. It is a issue with my current program, because the Java FX works fine...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I am using an separate Logger with a FileHandler. Does this maybe interfere with LocalLog? Setting the property works, but this does no change to the output.

ORMLite tries to detect and use other logging libraries if available.  I suspect that it is finding another logging implementation and use it.  You can force it to use one logger however with:

```
System.setProperty("com.j256.ormlite.logger.type", "LOCAL");
```

or

```
-Dcom.j256.ormlite.logger.type=LOCAL
```

Then you can set the log level with:

```
System.setProperty("com.j256.ormlite.logger.level", "ERROR");
```

or

```
-Dcom.j256.ormlite.logger.level=ERROR
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I found the culprit:

Apache Commons Logging seems to cause an issue somewhere.... Not sure why, but removing it solved the issue.

If [Gray](https://stackoverflow.com/users/179850/gray) has an explanation for this, i will mark his answer as the solved one. But for now I have my problem solved.

EDIT: If you still need Commons.Logging for your Application to work, you can use this:

```
System.setProperty("org.apache.commons.logging.Log",
     "org.apache.commons.logging.impl.NoOpLog");
```

This removed all the messages from ORMLite.